# Recursion Append: One list decreases by one member each time and returns many list of integers that we want to merge

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, append

**Recursion Append:  One list decreases by one member each time and returns many list of integers that we want to merge**

I look for this result:
[0,0,0,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,4,4]

```
So far I get the subsolutions :
[4,4]

**But I can not concatenate the rest of the solutions**
[2] 
[3,3,3] 
[5,5,5]
[0,0,0]
```

But this one does not work

```
/* Merge the subsolutions recursive. THIS IS THE ONE THAT DOES NOT WORK */
mergeB(S,[],[A]) :- block(S,A).
mergeB(S,X,[L|Tail],[Tail|A])  :- block(S,A), quitaUltimo(S,M), mergeB(M,X,Tail).
```

Comment: I don't know if it's just me, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. Perhaps you should explain a bit more how you go from [(3,5),(6,3),(9,2),(10,4),(12,0)] to [0,0,0,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,4,4].

Comment: This is very unclear. I don't even see a specific question here. And you have the statement, *So far I get the subsolutions: `[4,4],[2],[3,3,3],[5,5,5],[0,0,0]`*, but don't indicate at all what query you ran to get that, or how it's relevant to whatever question you may have.

Comment: I indicate the query.  % block([(3,5),(6,3),(9,2),(10,4),(12,0)], L2).
 % L2= [4,4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I still don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, but taken from bits and pieces you stated:

*"The idea is next: From a list of coordinates: L=[...], I look for this result: [0,0,0,5,5,5,3,3,3,2,4,4]
So far I get the subsolutions: [4,4],[2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reverse/2),[3,3,3],[5,5,5],[0,0,0].
... I want to merge all this solutions."*

And it **seems** you are trying to recursively append all of the sublists so all separate results will end in one resulting list.

If this is correct, what you want is actually very simply called [flatten](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=flatten/2).

Example output with your input data:

```
?- flatten([[4,4],[2],[3,3,3],[5,5,5],[0,0,0]],Result).
   Result = [4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note:  I see your data is also in reversed order of what you are trying to accomplish. If you cannot get your code fixed recursive-wise while building your result, then perhaps you can just do it afterwards with [reverse](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reverse/2).

So, all put together:

```
?- reverse([[4,4],[2],[3,3,3],[5,5,5],[0,0,0]],R), flatten(R,RFlat).
   R = [[0, 0, 0], [5, 5, 5], [3, 3, 3], [2], [4, 4]],
   RFlat = [0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4]
```

**EDIT**

Some thoughts:

I see you are getting the last 2 elements of a list to process them and then recursively want keep doing that for the same list, only now with the last element removed. You could go for a reversed list approach here, but another way to go would be something like:

```
% Gets last two elements and returns the list with last one removed
last2_and_rest([X,Y],X,Y,[X]).
last2_and_rest([H|T],X,Y,[H|A]) :- last2_and_rest(T,X,Y,A).
```

This way you could write something like:

```
% Base case (*)
foo([_],[]).

% Recursively calls block on last 2 elements of list and removes last elem
foo(List,[SubResult|R]) :-
    last2_and_rest(List,X,Y,Rest),
    block(X,Y,SubResult),
    foo(Rest,R).
```

to execute the block logic on the last 2 elements, remain the same list with the last element removed and recursively keep doing that for every pair of elements in the resting list. When only one more element is left in the list, we can no longer call last2_and_rest since this will give false and thus we write our base case (*) accordingly.

Note that I still don't understand the logic you are trying to execute, so this code does not take into account whatever has to happen with/before/after/.. the call to block/2, but you already stated that that part is working and you're just having trouble with the merging of subresults.

When this code executes -and you add your logic correctly-, you will get a result like [[0,0,0],[5,5,5],[3,3,3],...], which you can then flatten like I explained above.

Comment: Thanks. But, how I merge the subsolutions? That is my main issue. I have written the whole code if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am a beginner in Prolog and I was turning crazy trying to do this. Other things are simple but I could not believe that something so basic could be so complicated. Thanks for answering that fast as well.